# iterator is iterating for no reason c++

Tags: c++, iterator

So I am trying to implement an insert function, which inserts an element into the correct order on the list.

my input goes as:

```
  b.insert('Z');
  b.insert('J');
  b.insert('Y');
```

and should output as:

`J Y Z`

I start off by making my iterator point at the beginning of the list and then iterate through each object until I find the correct spot to enter it in. I don't understand why, but when I start off with the iteration, it jumps ahead one spot after it enters the loop.

```
class list < node<T>* >::iterator itr = bt->level().begin();

      cout << "itr now: " << (*itr)->getItem() << endl;

      while (itr != bt->level().end()) {
        cout << "itr now: " << (*itr)->getItem() << " and " << elem << endl;

        // do a bunch of other stuff
        ++itr;
      }
```

my output for this should look like:

```
itr now: Z
itr now: Z and J
itr now: J
itr now: J and Y
```

but instead it comes out as

```
itr now: Z
itr now: Z and J
itr now: J
itr now: Z and Y
```

can somone tell me whats happening thats causing this problem?

Comment: Reduce the problem down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). What is `elem`? What is in `//do a bunch of other stuff`? How does the second line ever get reached again? This code does not answer any of these crucial questions.

Comment: @Mankarse theres too much code to copy/paste into the OP. `//do a bunch of other stuff` pretty much checks where the item fits when compared to `itr->getItem()` and inserts it into that area with `insert`. I don't think the problem lies anywhere inside that part, because itr prints out `J` before going into the loop, but once it enters it pritns `Z`

Comment: I am afraid but we cannot help you if you don't post a complete example.

Comment: Unless you post a complete piece of code, there's no chance of you getting an answer.. There's nothing wrong with what you have above so the problem is obviously in the code you're not supplying! (for example: if you're inserting into the container somewhere in the 'hidden' code, then you're 'probably changing the iterator, but we can't tell without seeing the code!

Comment: For starters, you might post the code for `list`.  It's obviously not `std::list`, since `std::list` doesn't have an `insert` function which takes only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete code here, if you are looking for sorted order then just insert the element in `container` and use standard `algorithm sort` that would do the trick for you.

Comment: im asking why the iterator is jumping ahead when it enters the loop, theres no code between the `while` loop and the `cout` statement, I don't see why any of the code below the `cout` statement would affect what is printed seeing as the beginning of the list on the second of the time around is correct

Comment: @SNpn: rule #1 when asking others for help: if they say they need some information, give it to them. Otherwise you are just wasting everyone's time.